# Why ASP.NET website customErrors mode="Off" not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

Our ASP.NET 4.0 web application on production server (Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit with IIS7.5) is not showing detailed error message despite adding the following settings in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

According to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx), we should get the detailed error message but we are getting the following custom error message that's displayed on an error page that we direct to in the "`catch`" block of `try/catch` when an error occurs:

> Application has encounter an error, please try again later. If the problem persists please contact the system admin at: ....."

We also tried [this suggestion](http://chuchuva.com/pavel/2010/08/how-to-enable-detailed-error-information-for-iis-and-asp-net/) but still on an error on the `try/catch` block the above message gets displayed. We even restarted the IIS to make sure the web.config changes get applied but not luck. We have made sure the above settings are not repeated in the web.config file and that there are no other web.config files in the app.

**Edit**
Moreover, we do not have `<deployment ...>` element in the machine.config file that means according to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228298%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `<deployment retail="false"`> is the default.

Comment: It depends on the nature of an error whether or not it's possible to render a readable error message. See the Application event log as an additional source for the errors.

Comment: @abatishchev, I've checked the Application event log on the server and there is no related message there. There error occurs in the try() block of our C# code and it goes to the catch() block where we are redirecting user to our own customized error message. Instead of our customized error message we temporarily want to see the actual error message on the production server so we can find the issue.

Comment: @nam then remove the try/catch... or just log the error into a database/file since you are already catching it (seems like this should already be something you are doing?). Try/catches shouldn't be catching *unexpected* errors (in my opinion, like through just catching `Exception` instead of `WebException` or `FormatException` or any other exception you'd expect to happen)... kind of defeats the purpose and leads to problems like this.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, does this mean that if in the catch block we redirect a user to a custom error page, the <customErrors mode="Off"/> setting in web.config will have no effect and the error will always be redirected (from the catch block) to our custom error page - and no detailed error message generated by ASP.NET will be displayed?

Comment: @nam you are correct. I'll try to explain further in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are catching the error and then redirecting to the error page, so there is no unhandled error -- meaning no error is bubbling up to cause a "Yellow Screen Of Death" (which is what you will see when `mode="Off"`).

Granted, you **don't** want `mode="Off"` on production because it is revealing. `mode="RemoteOnly"` will only YSOD locally and is the preferred method.

To test and see a YSOD, put `throw new Exception();` directly after `Page_Load` (outside of a try/catch block) and then run the page locally.

Since you are already catching the exception, you *could* have some sort of error handling that logs the error details (what you are looking for) to a database or file so you can check to see what is happening with your website. Though I don't really agree with this method because then:

1. You apparently are catching *unexpected* exceptions which means you are unaware of potential problems with your site because they are being hidden, and
2. you have to put error handling / redirects in every page. You don't need to do this.

Instead, consider using [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/)  which is [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/) and provides an easy way to log errors (or you could implement your own custom logging from the `global.ascx`).

Then, stop catching *all* exceptions. Just catch exceptions you *expect* to happen and don't care that they happen and don't want to log (like a `FormatException` on a conversion). *Unexpected* exceptions will now bubble up, get logged by Elmah, and then you can use CustomErrors to redirect/display an error page... and you don't need to do any of this on the actual page's code behind (which saves you from putting error handling on every code-behind of every page). Elmah logs and lets you view the YSOD anytime you want. If you go this route, which is much easier than rolling your own error handling in the `global.ascx`, just make sure you secure elmah.

Comment: thank you for clarifying the use of customErrors mode and the handled vs. unhandled errors. Reading through the [MSDN definition of customErrors] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx) I did not find the mentioning of handled and unhandled errors in the context of customErrors mode. Reading a response from James Jardine at the end of the article also made things a bit clear on Custom Error Vs. ASP.NET Error in the context of customErrors mode.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue running a .NET (Core) application in IIS, you can instead send the output of the exception to a log file by setting stdoutLogEnabled="true" and stdoutLogFile="C:\Users\SomeUser\LoggingDirectory\LogFileName". In this case, you'll get a log file named something like LogFileName_20220607193533_9648.txt.

BE SURE TO RESET IIS.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Project.Name.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\Users\SomeUser\LoggingDirectory\LogFileName" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Disclaimer: I'm not certain that you need the "customErrors mode='Off'" part but, it was there when this solution worked for me.

Answer (score -8):

Sometime in the future, comment out the following code in `web.config`:

```xml
 <!--<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>-->
```

update the to the following code.

```xml
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" /><!--Depends on your version of .Net--->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" /><!-- Depends on your version of .Net--->
    <customErrors mode="Off"/> <!-- add this line--->
    <trust level="Full"/> <!-- add this line--->
</system.web>
```

Comment: Why would you recommend any of this?

Comment: @mason These things need to happen:
Reasons https://au.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/Problem-with-Windows-Web-Hosting-quot-this-program-is-blocked/td-p/14500..

Comment: That's in order to modify your application to be compatible with GoDaddy's configuration. And I don't know why you would suggest changing the authentication, custom error mode or whether the application compiles in debug or not. You really should learn exactly what these settings are before blindly suggesting them to others. I suggest you delete your answer so you don't confuse anyone.

Comment: @mason The orginal question was in regards to production server. I am sure this issue is faced by alot of people deploying project on production server mainly of the reason you just read on the link. I ended up on this page but the suggested soltuion does not solve issue. It is not specific to godaddy. Alot of hosting company do not allow compiling on their server.

Comment: Yes, they do. And you've suggesting completely unrelated changes such as changing the version of .NET used. Taking a scattershot approach to fixing problems is grossly irresponsible.

Comment: @masson  I am not asking to change the .Net version. It appears to me you are very opinionated with your solutions and forcing your way on to others. I will NOT delete the answer. It’s entirely up to community members to read the post and decide if the solution works for them or they can gain meaningful information. You have already down voted it.

Comment: Really? Then why do you say "update to the following code" and then provide 4.6.1 in that code? How are those even related to the issue at hand? Why would you provide them if they're completely unrelated? And why would you suggest setting customErrors mode to off on a production system?